# Why can't Tstringlist.LoadFromfile load a reasonably sized file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Compiling on a Win 10 system with 8GB memory for 32 bit.

Trying to load a 150Mb ASCII file using Tstringlist.Loadfromfile gives an "Out of Memory Error" with task manager reporting 1200Mb used.

Even with the 50% redundancy of Unicode can't explain that level of inefficiency!

Any idea whats going on?

Example code.

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var f:tstringlist;
begin
  if opendialog1.Execute then
  begin
    f:=Tstringlist.create;
    try
      f.Loadfromfile(Opendialog1.Filename);
    finally
      f.free
    end
  end;
end;

end.
```

As requested, some representitive text from the file below....

```
AcDbPolyline
 90
5
 70
0
 10
100091.01
 20
59019.75
 10
100077.39
 20
59001.49
 10
100070.7
 20
58974.72
 10
100066.85
 20
58942.73
 10
100065.12
 20
58920.69
  0
LWPOLYLINE
  5
```

Notepad++ reports the file as having 27 million lines.

Comment: Ask yourself what the system is going to do with that 8GB in a 32 bit process. It can only address 2GB. You'll get 4GB address space if you enable LARGEADDRESSAWARE in the PE options. I suspect that there is more to this than meets the eye, because a simple program to load such a file will succeed I believe.

Comment: More likely in my view is that you are actually trying to load this into a GUI control. I have no difficulty loading a 190MB text file into a string list. In fact I can load that file into three different instances (all in memory at the same time). Only on the fourth do I get an out of memory error. So, I suggest you work harder to provide a reproduction, and be a little less belligerent.

Comment: I have updated the code to show a complete unit. I created a new vcl project added a button and an open dialog and loaded the file.

Comment: As I said, I managed to load 3 190MB text files. What's different about your scenario that means you cannot load a single 150MB file? Is there something special about the file? Are the strings very short? How many lines are there? Try to appreciate that details matter.

Comment: The file is a map of london in ASCII dxf format, it loads up in Notepad++ no probs. You can download one yourslf and try it from https://cadmapper.com/#metro

Comment: BTW, i recompiled in 64 bit mode. Tstringlist wants 1500Mb to load a 160Mb file.

Comment: I won't help you if you won't answer my questions. I do t want to download and immense file. All I need is something representative added to the question. I think the answer is easy enough but you've got to ask the question properly.

Comment: I gave you a link where you can get a large DXF text file that will display the problem. Other than posting all the 160MB in a comment, what else can I do?

Comment: @Andyk If you can boast about loading the file in Notepad++ I'm pretty sure you're quite capable of providing a line count. I've taken a quick look at the DXF format, and the lines are fairly short. So the line count is going to be high.

Comment: You could answer my questions for a start. And you could post some representative excerpts as I asked. Do you want help or not. BTW, there's only one explanation of what you report so once you fix the question you'll get an answer.

Comment: @Craig, I have updated the post with the requested information.

Comment: Thanks for that. The question is now answerable.

Comment: @Andyk You'd be better off reading the data directly into a structure designed specifically to hold this data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each string requires a separate heap allocation. Each heap allocation yields a block of memory, but also some meta data that is used by the memory manager. On top of that the string has its own meta data, reference count and length.

If your file contains a lot of very short lines then the meta data can easily dominate. In extremis a single character string could easily consume 20 bytes or more. Off the top of my head, I don't know the actual overhead figures, so this is a guesstimate.

With very short lines there will be a lot of strings. The array of pointers owned by the string list could itself be very large. And if allocated by resizing memory could result in fragmentation. You say there are 27 million lines. At two pointers per line, one the string and one for its associated object, that's over 200MB alone.

All in all a `TStringList` is the wrong type for your task. You may best off reading the file line by line with a string reader object. Or loading the entire file into memory and using a dedicated type to map lines to offsets, as a text editor does. In fact text editors typically use memory mapping to avoid address space crises. Without knowing what you want to do with the file, it's hard to make recommendations but I hope I've helped you understand why your current approach has no future.

Comment: I guess this must be correct, still a 10 times increase in size to represent the data is horribly inefficient by any standard and they should have used the method you describe as standard in the design. What you are saying is that Stringlists should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Each string in recent versions of Delphi has a 16 byte prefix. (Older versions it was 8). Each entry in `TStringList` has pointer to StringListItem, the string itself and to an associated object (i.e. +12 bytes). So minimum 24 byte overhead per string. This is before considering that FastMem overhead uses a little padding to try reduce some of the fragmentation (in small alloc range will probably average < 5 bytes but still it's overhead per string). So an estimate of 30 byte overhead per string is actually conservative. And that would cap an absolute maximum of 30 mil lines in 1.2GB.

Comment: It's just the wrong type for your needs. `TStringList` is meant for managing smaller lists of strings, not huge files like this. It's fine for what it is designed for, but it's just not what you need.

Comment: OK, I've marked this as an answer. I am going to have to do a lot more work than I expected now for a fairly simple task. Sorry for the initail crabbiness, but when people ask me for code on how to call a standard library function, I get a little annoyed.

Comment: Usually there's a good reason for people asking the question. Here we needed to flush out the data rather than the code.

Comment: @Andyk: I don't see the point in your getting annoyed. You're asking us for **free help** to solve **your problem**, but getting snarky with us when asked for clarification.  Seems like a bad idea to me. Not conducive to getting people to want to help.

Comment: Help which we choose to give willingly. So I wouldn't feel in our debt or anything like that. And as far as getting snarky goes, every single time I pick Ken up on anything, it's a massive snark fest, so make of that what you will.....